# while true python doesn't work as intended

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, keyboard

I'm trying to run an instruction continuosly and only when I press "e" the loop must stop, the code is:

```
while True:
    Code = "Hello world"
    print(Code)
    if keyboard.read_key() == "e":
        break
```

The problem I get is that only when I press another key (not "e") on the keyboard it prints "hello world" but I want the code to print it even if I don't press anything

Answer (score 1):

The point is that keyboard.read_key() is waiting for you to insert a key, think at it as an input